# Chrome on Android has just eaten all my data plan

Tags: chrome-for-android, mobile-data, data-connection, data-monitoring, background-data

I am using Chrome on Nexus 5X.
Nothing like this ever happened until the last 2 days - my data plan was depleted suddenly, the carrier's app claimed that I have no more data, and when I checked my data usage in Android Settings, I got this:

[image]

WTF?
I didn't do anything special with Chrome in the last 2 days, my occasional Facebook browsing (no videos) has no way to reach that amount.
Is there any way to check inside Chrome which website did this? Or is it a Chrome bug?

Comment: Go into Settings app > Apps> Chrome> Storage> Manage Space>Manage. That would show you website-wise data consumption. Not sure how accurate that is.

Comment: Didn't show anything useful or related.